# Differential equation where one solution induces a set of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a differential equation of the form:

$$y' = f\left(\frac{y}{x}\right);\space\space\space x ≠ 0$$

where $f$ is any continuous function. I want to show that if $y(x)$ solves this equation, the function $y_a(x) := a y(\frac{x}{a})$ with $a ≠ 0$ also solves this function.

Can these functions $y_a(x)$ be seen as "stretching" an existing solution with $(0, 0)$ in the center? I don't really know how I can show that $y_a(x)$ is another solution indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just show that $y_a$ satisfies your equation. We have
$$ y_a'(x) = a y'\left(\frac xa\right) \cdot \frac 1a = y'\left(\frac xa\right)$$
by the chain rule. Now, as $y$ is a solution, we have for any $z \ne 0$ that 
$$ y'(z) = f\left(\frac{y(z)}z\right) $$
We use $z = \frac xa$ and get
$$ y_a'(x) = y'\left(\frac xa\right) = f\left(\frac{y(\frac xa)}{\frac xa}\right) = f\left(\frac{ay(\frac xa)}{x}\right) = f\left(\frac{y_a(x)}{x}\right) $$
So $y_a$ is a solution if $y$ is.